# Find number of iterations until a value reaches a limit

Tags: math

I have two numbers `X` and `Y` and the following pseudocode:

```
i = 0
While X < Y:
   X = X + complex_formula
   i += 1
Print i
```

`complex_formula` is independent from the X and its previous value.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to calculate the `i` without doing the iterations.

Comment: Is complex_formula also independent of `i` and timing? If so then it's a constant and this is just simple math: `i = Ceiling( (Y - X)/complex_formula)` and `X = X + i*complex_formula`.

Comment: Yes. It is independent and your comment worked. So, please, add it as an answer so I can choose it :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is complex_formula also independent of i and timing? If so then it's a constant and this is just simple math:

```
i = Ceiling( (Y - X)/complex_formula)
X = X + i*complex_formula
```